# WinJS.UI.ListView: Binding to the '-ms-grid-column' and -'ms-grid-row'

Tags: listview, binding, winjs

I'm creating a list of items that I want to bind to a WinJS.UI.ListView. The items are created as follows:

```js
var cells = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        var cell = {
            location: { x: i, y: j }
        };

        cells.push(cell);
    }
}
```

This list is binded to the WinJS.UI.ListView

```html
<div id="itemTemplate" data-win-control="WinJS.Binding.Template">
    <div style="width: 150px; height: 150px; margin: 10px;" data-win-bind="-ms-grid-column: location.y; -ms-grid-row: location.x ">
        <h2 data-win-bind="innerText: location.x"></h2>
        ,
        <h2 data-win-bind="innerText: location.y"></h2>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView" data-win-options="{ 
        itemDataSource : Data.itemList.dataSource,
        itemTemplate: select('#itemTemplate'),
        layout: {type: WinJS.UI.GridLayout} }"
    style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
</div>
```

The layout of the ListView is set '*WinJS.UI.GridLayout*' so I want to bind the '*-ms-grid-column*' and '*-ms-grid-row*' style properties to the X and Y properties of the location object in the itemTemplate. Binding the items to the list works like a charm, but binding the the column and row property throws an exception.

What is wrong here? Can anybody point me the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-ms-grid-column` and `-ms-grid-row` are not attributes of a `div`, and `data-win-bind` will not bind CSS attributes -- it binds HTML attributes.  You could instead try something like:

```
<div data-win-bind="style: location SomeLocationToStyleConverter">
```

You would have to build an initializer or converter (in this case named `SomeLocationToStyleConverter`) that could take the complex location object and return the entire value of the style attribute

Comment: Thanks. But in the example on [Quickstart: binding data and styles (Windows Store apps using JavaScript and HTML)]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700358.aspx they are binding to the background property on the style object. Is the difference?

Comment: If you can set the value in JavaScript with something like `myDiv.style.ms_grid_row` (which I don't know if it exists), then you can specify style.ms_grid_row in the binding arguments.  This would work for common styles like the background property you mentioned, but I don't know if the grid layout properties are available from there.  If you find they are, please add that comment here.